# Second highest number ArrayList

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist

So I got this code so far:

```
int secondLargest = list.get(0);
int largest = list.get(0);
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    if(list.get(i) > largest)
    {
        secondLargest = largest;
        largest = list.get(i);

        if(list.get(i) > secondLargest && list.get(i) != largest)
        {
            secondLargest = list.get(i);
        }
    }
}

System.out.print("Second biggest number ");
return secondLargest;
```

The problem is that when I use this code
(the list is:)

```
list2.add(1);
list2.add(2);
list2.add(10);
list2.add(9);
list2.add(8);
list2.add(7);
```

the "search" for the second highest number stops at 2, because 10 is the highest number. How do I fix this?

Comment: I think the easiest way to do this is to sort the array and take the second element (depending on the order, of course, so I'm assuming it is sorted in descending order). Moreover, a `SortedSet` can be used if you can make use of the Collections framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Put the second `if condition` outside the first if condition.

Because `second largest` is smaller than `largest` so you will never find it in the `if` block which check for the largest value.

```
int secondLargest = (int) list.get(0);
int largest = list.get(0);
for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
  if(list.get(i) > largest) {
    secondLargest = largest;
    largest = list.get(i);
  }
  if(list.get(i) > secondLargest && list.get(i) != largest) {
    secondLargest = list.get(i);
  }
}
System.out.print("Second biggest number ");
return secondLargest;
```

Comment: Note that fails if the second-largest number is the same as the largest number, assuming that the task will test this edge-case (read the requirements carefully).

Comment: @mk. you mean when list contains two largest values? I don't think OP is trying that. because this logic will not come in picture otherwise `list.get(i) != largest`.

Comment: -1: this fails when the list is sorted in descending order, and no two items have the same value (there is only one largest value) -- list.get(0) is the largest item in the list and list.get(1) is the second-biggest number, but this code prints "Second biggest number" and the value of list.get(0), when it should print the value of list.get(1).

Comment: make the second `if` an `else if` to the first.

Comment: not working for List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(10,2,9,4,5,9,6,6,8);

Answer (score 4):

Use `Arrays.sort(array);` and get the second element.

Comment: For a large array that's an expensive way to do this.

Comment: Sorting is `O(n.log(n))`, looping is `O(n)`, so it would be better to just loop.

Comment: Agreed, but no one asked about the asymptotic complexity. :)

Comment: @Keith you're not supposed to give the worst solution just because the OP did not specify a complexity

Comment: @Dici Who said it was the worst solution? You don't know the business requirements or his needs. My answer is 1 line of trusted code from Java's distribution; other answers require much more _custom_ code, thus more rigor in testing. You don't always need to build the ideal mouse trap, especially when considering the tradeoffs.

Comment: (Granted -- this is most likely a homework assignment that's intended to gain familiarity with loops and array structures)

Comment: @Keith well, yeah maybe in production code you would decide to use this for a small array... or you would write a quick select in a util class with some unit tests, and you would have a multi-purpose method available. This is the worst solution in terms of complexity, and if you're doing a trade-off with simplicity your answer should at least mention it. Anyway !

Answer (score 1):

You could first find the max number in the ArrayList using the Collections.max() function, once you have the max element, find the index of that element and get this removed from the array. Again use Collections.max() to find the second largest number in the array. Code as below

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
al.add(1);
al.add(2);
al.add(3);
al.add(4);
System.out.println(al);

int j = Collections.max(al);

System.out.println("Max in the array is " + j);
al.remove(al.indexOf(j));
int max2 = Collections.max(al);
System.out.println(max2);
```

Let me know if more details are needed around it.

Comment: This presumes the highest value to occur just once.

Answer (score 0):

Use two for loops. The first should find the largest number, and store its index position. The second should find the largest number that is not at the same index position as the previously found number. (This will ensure that you do not miss cases where the second-largest number is the same as the largest.)

If you think it is appropriate, use `Arrays.sort(array);` and get the second element as suggested by   ɐuıɥɔɐɯ.

Comment: Even for doing that you don't need the two loop. You can achieve in single loop. why to increase the complexity?

Comment: @YoungHobbit It actually reduces the complexity. For a novice (like the OP), it's much easier to understand "find the largest, then the largest that isn't that one" than it is to do checks in the middle of a loop. And it's still O(n), if that's what you mean by complexity :)

Comment: Comparing the index in the second iteration is not going to yield the second highest number if the highest one occurs more than once: compare the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class second_highest_array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //List<Integer> numlist = Arrays.asList(9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0);
        //List<Integer> numlist = Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
        //List<Integer> numlist = Arrays.asList(8,7,4,1,2,3,4,1,9,0,11,9,8);
        List<Integer> numlist = Arrays.asList(9,-8,5,4,1,7,3,2,6);
        int highestnum = numlist.get(0);
        int secondhighest = numlist.get(0);
        for(int numarr : numlist) {
            if(highestnum < numarr ) {
                secondhighest = highestnum ;
                highestnum = numarr;
            }else if(secondhighest < numarr && highestnum != numarr) {
                secondhighest = numarr;
            }else if(secondhighest == highestnum) {
                secondhighest = numarr;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("highest : "+highestnum +" :: Second Highest : "+secondhighest);
    }
}
```

Comment: we must need to add last else if condition other wise if your array is in desc order it will give wrong O/P , as in that case second highest and highest will be equal.

Comment: *must need to add [special casing `secondhighest == highestnum`]* just initialize `secondhighest` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Without sorting and linear solution:

```
    public int compute3(List<Integer> list) {
        int max = 0, secondMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE, pre = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
            pre = max;
            if(list.get(i)>max) {
                max = list.get(i);
            }
            if(list.get(i)<max && list.get(i)>secondMax ) {
                secondMax = list.get(i);
            } else if(pre>secondMax && pre<max){
                secondMax = pre;
            }
        }
        return secondMax;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Within the loop's first `if statement`, check versus the `second largest` rather than the `largest`. The below will get you going

```
    int secondLargest = list.get(0);
    int largest = list.get(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        if(list.get(i) > secondLargest)
        {
            if(list.get(i) > largest ) {
                secondLargest = largest;
                largest = list.get(i);
            } else {
                secondLargest = list.get(i);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Revision 1 doesn't work if item 0 is max.

Answer (score -1):

```
    HashSet integers = new HashSet<>(arrayList);
    ArrayList arrayList1 = new ArrayList(integers);
    return (int) arrayList1.get(arrayList1.size()-2);
```

Comment: HashSet has no sorted ordering. If I add into `arrayList` the numbers `1, 99, 1000, -4`, I get -4.